# Line Integral of f along close curve and Green's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I am trying to solve the following question.

> Let C be a simple closed curve in the plane with positive orientation bounding domain D in the plane. Which of the following integrals below is equal to the area of D?

I found that the answer to the above question is
$\int_C (2xy + y) dx + (x^2 + 3x) dy = \int_C Pdx + Qdy = \iint_D \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dA = \iint_D (2x+3) - (2x+2) dA = \iint_D 1 dA$

(Please correct me if I am wrong above.)

But I am not sure how to prove whether $ \int_C x ds $ equates to $\iint_D 1 dA$ or not.

To be exact, I am not sure of how to deal with ds and turn that into an integral with dx or dy to use Green's Theorem.

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Without explicitly knowing $C$ or $D$, there's no way to determine $\int_C x\,\mathrm ds$. Note that this is a scalar line integral, whereas Green's theorem addresses line integrals of vector fields. (In this case, the vector field is $\langle2xy+y,x^2+3x\rangle$.)

Comment: Ok I see. Yes Green's theorem addresses line integrals of vector fields and $\int_C x ds$ is a scalar line integral.